# How to set X-Forwarded-For with httputil.ReverseProxy

Tags: go, reverse-proxy

## Why would I want to do this

I have run in to this issue twice.

The first time was with a reverse proxy that lived inside an IPv6 only server network. Client requests come in through NAT46. The source-IP of the request becomes [fixed 96-bit prefix] + [32-bit client IPv4 address]. This means that the reverse proxy could always identify the real client IP. I couldn't find a way to set the `X-Forwarded-For` header to that address though. I got around it by modifying the backend server.

This time I have a reverse proxy which will run on Google App Engine. Requests hit Google's load balancer first, which adds the `X-Forwarded-For` header and forwards the request to my app. I want to modify the request a bit and then pass it to a backend server, which I cannot modify. The back-end needs the original client IP, and can accept it via `X-Forwarded-For` (it's authenticated, don't worry). In this case I want to pass the `X-Forwarded-For` header from Google's load balencer through unmodified.

## The Problem

It seems like there is no way to set `X-Forwarded-For` to a value that I chose when using [`httputil.ReverseProxy`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http/httputil#ReverseProxy). If I set it (option 1 below) the client address from the TCP connection will be appended. If if I set it to `nil` (option 2 below), it is omitted like the documentation suggests, but that's not what I want either.

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httputil"
)

func director(req *http.Request) {
    // currently running a PHP script that just records headers
    host := "bsweb02.bentonvillek12.org"

    // who we dial
    req.URL.Scheme = "https"
    req.URL.Host = host

    // host header
    req.Host = host

    // proof that most headers can be passed through fine
    req.Header["Foo"] = []string{"Bar"}

    req.Header["X-Forwarded-For"] = []string{"1.2.3.4"} // option 1
    //req.Header["X-Forwarded-For"] = nil               // option 2
}

func main() {
    http.ListenAndServe(":80", &httputil.ReverseProxy{
        Director: director,
    })
}
```

Option 1

```
array(9) {
  ["Content-Type"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["Content-Length"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["Foo"]=>
  string(3) "Bar"
  ["X-Forwarded-For"]=>
  string(18) "1.2.3.4, 127.0.0.1"
  ["User-Agent"]=>
  string(11) "curl/7.81.0"
  ["Host"]=>
  string(26) "bsweb02.bentonvillek12.org"
  ["Accept-Encoding"]=>
  string(4) "gzip"
  ["Accept"]=>
  string(3) "*/*"
  ["Connection"]=>
  string(5) "close"
}
```

Option 2

```
array(8) {
  ["Content-Type"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["Content-Length"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["Foo"]=>
  string(3) "Bar"
  ["User-Agent"]=>
  string(11) "curl/7.81.0"
  ["Host"]=>
  string(26) "bsweb02.bentonvillek12.org"
  ["Accept-Encoding"]=>
  string(4) "gzip"
  ["Accept"]=>
  string(3) "*/*"
  ["Connection"]=>
  string(5) "close"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have two options.

##### 1. Implement `http.RoundTripper`

You implement your own `RoundTripper` and re-set `X-Forwarded-For` in there. ([demonstration](https://go.dev/play/p/wEQ87txF1jk))

```
type MyRoundTripper struct{}

func (t *MyRoundTripper) RoundTrip(req *http.Request) (*http.Response, error) {
    req.Header["X-Forwarded-For"] = []string{"1.2.3.4"}
    return http.DefaultTransport.RoundTrip(req)
}

func main() {
    http.ListenAndServe(":80", &httputil.ReverseProxy{
        Director: director,
        Transport: &MyRoundTripper{},
    })
}
```

When the `Transport` field isn't set on `httputil.ReverseProxy` it falls back to `http.DefaultTransport`, so you can fall back to it too after your custom code.

##### 2. Unset `req.RemoteAddr`

You reset the original request's `RemoteAddr` field before invoking the reverse proxy. This field is set by the HTTP server and, when present, triggers the `X-Forwarded-For` replacement in the reverse proxy implementation. ([demonstration](https://go.dev/play/p/LV0eZVn8rbu))

```
func main() {
    http.ListenAndServe(":80", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        r.RemoteAddr = ""
        proxy := &httputil.ReverseProxy{ Director: director } 
        proxy.ServeHTTP(w, r)    
    })
}
```

However this behavior relies on an implementation detail, which may or may not change in the future. I recommend using option 1 instead.